# Pass float to and from app delegate in iphone dev

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iphone app that has multiple view controllers. I'm currently able to pass an int value to and from the app delegate as follows (I want to use float instead!, but not sure how):

**app delegate.h**

```
@interface { 
    NSInteger accumulatedTime;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger accumulatedTime;

@end
```

**app delegate.m**

```
@implementation

@synthesize accumulatedTime;
```

then in my view controller.h

```
@interface {
    int secs2;
}
```

**view controller.m**

```
BetaTeam1AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (BetaTeam1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

secs2 = mainDelegate.accumulatedTime ;
```

I want to use a float instead, Easy enough to change int to float in the view controllers .h and .m but how to code in the app delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the type of `accumulatedTime` to `float`. `float` and `int` are no different here; both are just C types, and properties can return C types.

That said, you should probably make `accumulatedTime` be of type `NSTimeInterval`, as this will be more consistent with Cocoa time routines. `NSTimeInterval` is generally implemented as a `double`.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I will do some reading on NSNumber and NSTimeInterval. 
PS. Best response and response I have gotten, much better then the idev forums.

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber can encapsulate a CGFloat.

```
NSNumber *accumulatedTime;
CGFloat secs2 = [mainDelegate.accumulatedTime floatValue];
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

So I use NSNUmber *accumulated time in the app delegate.h
Do I still use a property and synthesize ?
should property be (nonatomic, retain) or just (nonatomic)as with NSInteger?
Do I just use the CGFloat as:
CGFloat secs2 = [mainDelegate.accumulatedTime floatValue];
and 
[mainDelegate.accumulatedTime floatValue] = CGFloat secs2

and float secs2; to declare or CGFloat secs2;

Sorry, I am so thick, I will read the apple docs on CGFloat but thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing this global information in a different place, like a Model object in the MVC theme. Even if it's a Singleton, it's better design than filling up your App Delegate like this.